# Using $elemMatch to compare object fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a need to use `$elemMatch` in an aggregation pipeline and I need to compare 2 fields of an object from a nested array of objects:

Example collection:

```
name: 'xxx',
steps: [
{
  userId: 'abc',
  senderId: 'abc'
},
...
]
```

What I'm trying to do is return all that have at least 1 step where `userId = senderId`.

I have tried the following, but I get an error that `$expr` isn't allowed as a child of `$elemMatch`:

```
{
  $match: {
    steps: {
      $elemMatch: {
        $expr: { $eq: ['$userId', '$senderId'] },

      },
    },
  },
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[`$elemMatch`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#-elemmatch--projection-) can only be used in projection.

You can workaround for comparing fields in the array as below:

1. `$set` - Create new field `filteredCount` with get the array size `$size` of filtered array.
2. `$match` - Get `filteredCount` greater than 0.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $set: {
    filteredCount: {
      $size: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$steps",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.userId",
              "$$this.senderId"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $match: {
    "filteredCount": {
      $gt: 0
    }
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/llvYEY5ZDcP)

Comment: Thanks! looks like what I need - I will give it a go later today